# Geostatistics in SAGA: Strange variogram output

Tags: spatial-statistics, saga, variogram

I'm verry new to geostatistic. I'm using variogram to visualize a data (available in .shp [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kg9uzp-CBOx5s61rTDwqMVW2RWS61otZ/view?usp=sharing)). Then I got the data like this or from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18Yds5a15W7aI3PM4EWc4V4BbioFBWxch/view?usp=sharing) (updated zip files contains shp, shx, prj, mshp, dbf, cpg). The sensor value is in the column value (air pollution concentration).

[image]

The shapes look like "inverted" from the common variogram shape. Is it violating any law? Or is there another type of data that has variogram like that?

Update:
Steps

1. csv data contain lat, lon, physical value (eg temperature). the data is taken in the morning from several days
2. import to SAGA GIS, projecting to wgs72 to get meter unit
3. geoprocessing > spatial and geostatistics > variogram
4. scatter plot variance vs distance. there are also option of var. cum in the program

Comment: Can you add details about how you created the graph.  It looks like a covariogram.  Here is a similar example; https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Nonparametric-variogram-and-covariogram-estimation-Genton-Gorsich/a94c16e68ed9e80ed860e67b0b700165120277a2

Comment: 1. csv data contain lat, lon, physical value (eg temperature). the data is taken in the morning from several days
2. import to SAGA GIS, projecting to wgs72 to get meter unit
3. geoprocessing > spatial and geostatistics > variogram
4. scatter plot variance vs distance. there are also option of var. cum in the program

Comment: Please edit your question to include the information you just gave. In general, people do not look at the comments for additional information to answer questions. Perhaps you could also include a link to the data so people can compare your plot against their results when they run your data.

Comment: I haven't used Saga, so don't know exactly how the algorithm works.  Having said that, I would start by analyzing the output of step 3, creating the variogram.  How many pairs of points are there for each variogram point?  If there are very few, 10 or 20, try modifying the Initial number of distance classes or max distance to see if the number of pairs increases.

Comment: thanks for the response. okay, I've added the steps and also the link to the shp data. I think the number of pair is big enough (more than 20 or 30) since I think there are about 5000 data points in total. Do you have another software alternative for making variogram?

Comment: The data is Long/Lat & temperature.  Is the variogram distance in Long/Lat degrees?  If so try projecting it into something with meters like a UTM grid.

Comment: I tried your shapefile @martin, but it does not work. Shapefiles come as a group of files usually all with the same name but different file extensions (.prj, .cbf, .cpg, .sbn, .sbx, .shx), the best way to make them work is to share them all in a zip folder. Could you change the link to include all of the associated files you can find?

Comment: @PhillipAllen the attached pictures of the variogram i tried to make is already in meter. I projected the lat long to WGS72/UTM.

Comment: @saQuist the link is updated with theese files shp, shx, prj, mshp, dbf, cpg I could find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot help you with your implementation in SAGA GIS, but I believe the problem lies rather with the data than with the implementation.
I have been playing around with the data in `R`, so I'll share the scripts and outputs below. If you want to learn geostatistics in R, I recommend courses [DataCamp Spatial Stats in R](https://learn.datacamp.com/courses/spatial-statistics-in-r), and [DataCamp Spatial Data in R](https://learn.datacamp.com/courses/spatial-analysis-with-sf-and-raster-in-r).

So if we look at the data, we see that the sensor values are very skewed towards the left and that we do not have a clear spatial trend in the data. So, the sensor values do not seem to be dependent on their location.

```
# load packages 
require(sf)
require(rgstat)
require(magrittr)

# read the data 
sensordata <- read_sf("72_variogram_20210111_aoi_sore.shp")
sensordata$Value <- as.numeric(sensordata$Value) # transform value collumn to type numeric.

# plot histogram of sensor values
hist(sensordata$Value, main = "Histogram of Sensor Values") 
# plot map of the sensor values 
plot(sensordata["Value"], key.pos = 4, main = "Sensor Values")
```

[image: Histogram and map of sensor values]

We can decide to transform the data to make it more normally distributed. If we take for instance the log-transform, we start to see more of a pattern, but still, it doesn't help us as much. (Note that the interpretation of the data is getting more difficult when transforming your data)

```
# take a log transform of your data 
sensordata$logvalue <- log(sensordata$Value) 
hist(sensordata$logvalue, main = "Histogram of Log Transformed Sensor Values") 
plot(sensordata["logvalue"], key.pos = 4)
```

[image]

Now, let's look at the semivariogram. If we look at this [brief explanation of a semivariogram](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geostatistical-analyst/understanding-a-semivariogram-the-range-sill-and-nugget.htm), we expect some line that begins somewhere near the origin of the axis and continues in a straight line until it hits some plateau. The point closest to the origin signifies the "nugget", or your short distance variation. The plateau is the "sill", or the total variation in your data. The graph shows how the observations are dependent on distance. Usually, things that are close by are more similar than things that are far away. If it does not matter whether you are close by or far away, then there is no spatial dependency in your data, and your semivariogram is "pure nugget", or a straight horizontal line.

In your case, the semivariogram is odd indeed. To the left, we see the camel-shaped figure which would imply something like "if you are close by the observations are all over the place, but if you are further away (400m), the observations are more similar". But if we take the semivariogram of the transformed sensor values, we start to see more of a straight horizontal line.

```
# make a gstatVariogram object for the sensor values 
vgval <-   gstat(id = c("Value"), formula = Value~1, data = sensordata) %>% variogram()
# make a gstatVariogram object for the log transformed sensor values 
vglogval <-   gstat(id = c("logvalue"), formula = logvalue~1, data = sensordata) %>% variogram()
# plot the semivariograms 
plot(vgval, main = "Semivariogram of Sensor Values")
plot(vglogval, main = "Semivariogram of Log-Transformed Values")
```

[image: Semivariograms of sensor values and log-transformed sensor values]

So by transforming the data, we confirmed what could be concluded from the start, namely that the data is not spatially dependent. Because we see an almost straight horizontal line in the semivariogram, it does not matter whether you are far away or close by, the value of the observations are mostly similar. Therefore, the variation that is measured by your sensor does not depend on where you are, but by other things, like the time of the measurement or the calibration of your instrument for instance.

This is my conclusion based on the data as they were, without any context of the situation. If you believe there should be a spatial dependency in the data according to some variable you have recorded, I recommend you to subset the data over your desired variable, and run the variogram again.

Comment: thanks a lot. Yes I think I should subset the data set maybe per day to get the common variogram. Thankyou, I learned a lot :)